# Session value isn't recognized through controller in MVC Core 2.0. "Nullable object must have a value."

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core-mvc

So I'm trying to get a little login system started. When logged in I'd like to transfer the ID from the login method to the index method.

Here's my login method

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Login(Models.DB.Teacher m)
        {
            var teacher = await _context.Teacher
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync(p => p.Username == m.Username);
            if (teacher == null)
            {
                return View(m);
            }

            if (m.Password.ToLower() == teacher.Password.ToLower()) //Checks if pass is the same
            {
                HttpContext.Session.SetInt32("sessionID", teacher.Id);
                int _id = (int)HttpContext.Session.GetInt32("sessionID");

                return RedirectToAction("/Index/");

            }


            return View(m);
        }
```

Notice that the int _id = Session on above was just for a test. It worked in the same method.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
        {
            int _id = (int)HttpContext.Session.GetInt32("sessionID");
            var teacher = await _context.Teacher
                  .FirstOrDefaultAsync(p => p.Id == _id);

                return View(teacher);
        }
```

This is my error message. I realise it doesn't have any value but I'm clueless as to why.

```
InvalidOperationException: Nullable object must have a value.
System.Nullable<T>.get_Value()
fifty.Controllers.TeachersController.Index() in TeachersController.cs
+
            int _id = (int)HttpContext.Session.GetInt32("ID");
```

Comment: Need to determine what exactly is null. Is it HttpContext, session, or the particular verbal you’re trying to retrieve?

Comment: I don't have the slightest idea. I've used a breakpoint to try and getting deeper but without any success. I have tried to create an instance of HttpContext outside of methods but that's not allowed. All I know is that the data doesn't get transfered from the login to index method albeit it being a direct connection but that the session works if called right after. Somewhere inbetween the data get lost and I've no idea why.

Comment: You really need to learn how to attach to the process, debug, and inspect variables. Those are going to be critical skills if you’re going to be a  web developer. At the bare minimum, you could assign each of those properties to separate variables and dump their content to a log file.

Comment: I am not going to be a web developer and I'm just trying to scrape by with a minimum effort - the project doesn't require high-level and optimal coding, just trying to get by what I assumed to be a simple problem for real developers. Anyways thanks for your time

Comment: Anyways I'll just go with the id as a parameter instead.